# Angular 2 refreshing token by catching 401 globally

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I want to refresh access_token by catching 401 from the api. Im using laravel 5 passport.

After i catch the 401 in `extended-http.service.ts` my code wont send a post request to get updated `access_token`.

Iv'e tried multiple things but the only thing i can get working is the following code. The problem with this code is i'll have to add it to every single request inside my application which is not ideal. Id rather refresh token in my `extended-http.service.ts` 401 catch.

```
.catch(initialError => {
    if (initialError && initialError.status === 401) {
        console.log('we got here');
        this.RefreshService.refresh().flatMap((data) => {
            if (localStorage.getItem("access_token") != null) {
                // retry with new token
                return this.getUsers();
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(initialError);
            }
        });
    } else {
        return Observable.throw(initialError);
    }
})
```

The following code is what i have now to catch 401. But when i try to call `this.refreshToken.refresh();` inside the catcher i get the following error: `Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! Http ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1`

//app.module.ts

```
import { ExtendedHttpService } './services/extended-http.service.ts';
providers: [
    RefreshService
    {provide: Http, useClass: ExtendedHttpService },
]
```

// refresh.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Request, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Response, Http, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as globals from './../globals';
import { CustomQueryEncoderHelper } from './../shared/helpers';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Injectable()
export class RefreshService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    refresh() {
        let body = new URLSearchParams('', new CustomQueryEncoderHelper());
        body.set('grant_type', 'refresh_token');
        body.set('refresh_token', localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'));
        body.set('client_id', '2');
        body.set('client_secret', 'Crazy secret code');
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(globals.api + 'oauth/token', body, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
                localStorage.removeItem("refresh_token");
                localStorage.removeItem("expires_in");
                localStorage.setItem("access_token", data.access_token);
                localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", data.refresh_token);
                localStorage.setItem("expires_in", data.expires_in);
                location.reload();
            },
            (error) => {
                Observable.throw(error);
            }
            );
    }
}
```

//extended-http.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Request, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Response, Http, 
RequestOptionsArgs, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class ExtendedHttpService extends Http {

    constructor(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return super.request(url, options).catch((error: Response) => {
            if ((error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) &&
               (window.location.href.match(/\?/g) || []).length < 2) {
                console.log('The authentication session expires or the user is not authorised. Force refresh of the current page.');
                this.refreshToken.refresh(); // Doesn't work
                // How can i refresh token here?
        }
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
    }
}
```

So to recap i want to refresh token inside of `extended.service.ts` 401 catch. But i have no idea how i should make it work. Please help!

Comment: I have a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46795106/2945345. If I work it out, I will let you know

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but i found a way resolve it.

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
constructor(public toastr: ToastrService, public toastrConfig: ToastrConfig, private router: Router,
    private injector: Injector, private cookieService: CookieService) {
    toastrConfig.closeButton = true;
}
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.ingestionService = this.injector.get(IngestionService);
// HERE i create an instance of that.
}
```